# What is return type of findOneAndUpdate(updateQuery, updateSet, returnFields), and how to get the values that are returned?

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to update some fields in DB and also want to it to return some fields, can you suggest how to retrieve the return fields?

so i am using here,

```
returnFields := map[string]interface{}{"order_id":1} 

data := FindAndUpdateVerticalsOffers(updateQuery, updateFields, returnFields)
```

**How to get order_id from "data":**

```
func FindAndUpdateVerticalsOffers(updateQuery map[string]interface{}, updateFields interface{}, returnFields map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {

    session := db.GetSession()
    defer session.Close()
    collection := session.DB("").C(VerticalsOffersName)
    updateSet := bson.M{"$set": updateFields}
    return collection.FindOneAndUpdate(updateQuery, updateSet, returnFields)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to update some fields in DB and also want to it to return some fields,

If you're using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) (currently v1.1), you can utilise [FindOneAndUpdate()](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.FindOneAndUpdate) which finds a single document and updates it, returning either the original or the updated.

The method accepts argument for [FindOneAndUpdateOptions](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#FindOneAndUpdateOptions), which supports [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). For example:

```
collection := client.Database("dbName").Collection("collName")

// Sets projection (or return fields)
findUpdateOptions := options.FindOneAndUpdateOptions{}
findUpdateOptions.SetProjection(bson.M{"order_id": 1})

result := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(context.TODO(), 
                                      bson.M{"foo":1}, 
                                      bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"bar":1}}, 
                                      &findUpdateOptions)

doc := bson.M{}
err = result.Decode(&doc)
```

The above query will match a document where field `foo` is 1, update field `bar` to 1, and return only `order_id` as the result. Note that by default the `_id` field is also returned. You can [suppress the _id field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field) from being projected by setting it to 0.

Please note that the return type of `FindOneAndUpdate` is a [SingleResult](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#SingleResult) object, which represents a single document returned from an operation. If the operation returned an error, the `Err` method of SingleResult will return that error.